# export HTML table

Tags: javascript, excel

I try to export a HTML table to excel, but does not export more that 174 rows.

```
        a.href = data_type + ', ' + encodeURIComponent(tab_text);


        a.download = 'Report_' + postfix + '.xls';


        a.click();
```

this code works perfectly for Chrome but when exceed 174 rows fails.

Comment: You should provide more information about what you've tried, where do these variables come from?  what are they?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For UTF 8 Conversion and Currency Symbol Export Use this, check it out:

```
var tableToExcel = (function() {
  var uri = 'data:application/vnd.ms-excel;base64,'
    , template = '<html xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office" xmlns:x="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:excel" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40"><head><!--[if gte mso 9]><?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?><x:ExcelWorkbook><x:ExcelWorksheets><x:ExcelWorksheet><x:Name>{worksheet}</x:Name><x:WorksheetOptions><x:DisplayGridlines/></x:WorksheetOptions></x:ExcelWorksheet></x:ExcelWorksheets></x:ExcelWorkbook></xml><![endif]--></head><body><table>{table}</table></body></html>' 
    // you can also change the code template.
    , base64 = function(s) { return window.btoa(unescape(encodeURIComponent(s))) }
    , format = function(s, c) { return s.replace(/{(\w+)}/g, function(m, p) { return c[p]; }) }
  return function(table, name) {
      if (!table.nodeType) table = document.getElementById(table)
      var ctx = { worksheet: name || 'Worksheet', table: table.innerHTML }
    window.location.href = uri + base64(format(template, ctx))
  }
})()
```